# MongoDB Bulk Save Equivalent?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am a mongodb noob and am running into some difficulty trying to create an equivalent to bulk save (as I can't find a bulk save operation) using the [MongoDB bulk operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/).  Briefly, given an array of documents:

```
[{ _id:1, name:"a" ... }, { _id:1, name:"b" ... } ... ]
```

I want to bulk upsert the documents in the array, using the _id attribute as the comparison field to determine which incoming records are equivalent to records already in mongodb.  In pseudo-code I want mongodb to bulk upsert as follows:

```
if(incomingDocument._id == existingDocument._id){
  update(incoming) // overwrite existing document with entire incoming document
} else {
  insert(incoming)
}
```

Ideally, I would like to pass mongo an array and an comparator vs queuing up an individual bulk operation for each document.

How/can I do this with `Bulk.find().upsert().update(<update>);` or similar ? 
(Alternately, is there an undocumented bulk save() operation?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bulk.find.upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/)

> With the upsert option set to true, if no matching documents exist for
>   the Bulk.find() condition, then the update or the replacement
>   operation performs an insert. If a matching document does exist, then
>   the update or replacement operation performs the specified update or
>   replacement.

But you will need to loop over your collection:

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
myDocumnets.forEach(function(doc) {
  bulk.find({_id: doc._id}).upsert().replaceOne(doc);
});
bulk.execute({w: 1, j: true}, function (err, result) {
  if (result.isOk()) {
    ...
}
```

More, or less, I am sorry I am not able to test it at the moment. I am also not able to say how it will behave on large amounts of documents.

**UPDATE**

I modified code, as suggested by Colin.

Comment: I mentioned save() in the question. The problem is getting something similar to work in mongodb's bulk mode (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/).  Moreover, the save API only claims to take a single document at at time, is there way to pass it an array?

Comment: @Colin sorry, I've misread your question. I don't think there is a `Bulk.save()` operation.

Comment: No worries. Is there a way to work around it using bulk upsert?

Comment: @Colin see my update, but I am pretty sure it will require some modifications.

Comment: Yes, this is the same approach I referred to at the end of the question.  You can see my test here: http://pastebin.com/KwXDrHwP.  I haven't been able to make it work, yet.

Comment: @Colin Why it's not working? Is there any errors? I am not sure, but there might be some convertion problems (JSON vs BSON).

Comment: I am getting write errors saying: "Cannot update '_id' and '_id' at the same time".
code is now http://pastebin.com/bHTYxmCm

Comment: Use `bulk.find({_id: doc._id}).upsert().replaceOne(doc);` instead, in the `forEach looping`.